# How to position an image inside a DIV with dynamic height with pure CSS/HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV with two column DIVs inside. The main DIV's height is not defined, it's adjusted to the text in the second column instead.

My problem is: how to position an image in the first column, so it's eg. 80% from the beginning of the text in the second column. I tried simply setting `top: 80%` but the browser ignores that and puts the image on top of the column.

NOTE: I know I could just get the height of the main DIV in px via Javascript/jQuery, and set the first column's height to that manually, but the solution I need should use only CSS/HTML.

My code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="charset=UTF-8">

<style type= "text/css">
html{
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
}
body {font-family: Georgia; height:99%; margin: 0.25% 0}
div {position: relative}
p {text-align: justify; font-size: 15pt; margin-left: 0}
img {position:absolute}

#cntr {
    width: 1200px;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
    min-height:100%;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #708090">
<div id="cntr">
<div style="left:50px; width:1100px">
<div style="width:300px; height:100%">
<img src="zdj/cho1.jpg" style="top: 80%">
</div>
<div style="left:350px; width:750px">
/* some long <p>'s of text here */
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

EDIT: 80% refers to the height of the text DIV (eg. if the text is 2000px high then I want the image to begin at 1600th pixel from the top of the first column.

Comment: Try `margin-top` instead of `top`

Comment: what do you mean by 80% from text begining ? is it from the size of image, from how long is text text (1-1000 lines ?) what are those 80% refers to ?

Comment: Do you want your image aligned to bottom?

Comment: @SumerSingh Edited the question to clarify what I mean by the 80%.

Comment: @GCyrillus Edited to clarify what the 80% means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a fluid layout + position:relative might do (even if i do not get the whole point here). Size of that image, overflowing container, ....

```html
<div id="cntr">
  <div style="display:table;table-layout:fixed; width:1100px;border:solid;margin-bottom:100px;">
    <div style="width:300px; display:table-cell;position:relative;text-align:center">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/&text=What_Size" style="position:absolute;top: 80%">
    </div>
    <div style="display:table-cell;border:solid; width:750px">
      <p>some long 's of text here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <div style="display:table;table-layout:fixed; width:1100px;border:solid;">
    <div style="width:300px; display:table-cell;position:relative;text-align:center">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/&text=What_Size" style="position:absolute;top: 80%">
    </div>
    <div style="display:table-cell;border:solid; width:750px">
      <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

      <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris
        placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
        tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

      <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

      <ol>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
        <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
      </ol>

      <blockquote>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus
          turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
      </blockquote>

      <h3>Header Level 3</h3>

      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
        <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
      </ul>

      <pre><code>
#header h1 a { 
 display: block; 
 width: 300px; 
 height: 80px; 
}
</code></pre>
    </div>
```

Beside, if image doesn't have to be in  the HTML, a background-position will do:

```css
div {
  padding-left:300px;
  width:800px;
  border:solid;
  margin:auto;
  background:url(http://dummyimage.com/100x100/ff00ff/00ff00&text=80perc_from_top) no-repeat 20px 80%
}
```

```html
<div >
      <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

      <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris
        placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
        tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

      <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

      <ol>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
        <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
      </ol>

      <blockquote>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus
          turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
      </blockquote>

      <h3>Header Level 3</h3>

      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
        <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
      </ul>

      <pre><code>
#header h1 a { 
 display: block; 
 width: 300px; 
 height: 80px; 
}
</code></pre>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your idea from the first snippet with some positioning changes (like adding `left: 50px` margins solved my problem. Thanks! Unfortunately, I can't give you +1 because I'm too small yet :(

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your html and css, try this one. Now your image and text are not overlapping. You can set the percentage from 80% to any according to your requirements.

```
    <body style="background-color: #708090">
    <div id="cntr">
        <div style="left:50px; width:1100px">
            <div style="width:230px; height:100%; float:left;">
                <img src="zdj/cho1.jpg" style="margin-top:80%">
            </div>
            <div style="float:right; width:60%;">
                /* some long <p>'s of text here */
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think the columns don't overlap already, because the left one has `width: 300px`, and the right one is positioned `left: 350px`. Also, why do I need to change the widths of the columns? I want them to be as wide as they're now.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work :( The image moves down a little bit, but not as much as 80%

Comment: as per you html it was overlapping, and the image is down beacuse you have set it to 80%, I mentioned this in the answer you can change it to any value as per your requirements.

Comment: can you please elaborate whats your actual requirement here, its little bit confusing now.

Answer (score 0):

edit your #cntr css like :-

```
#cntr {
    width: 1200px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
    min-height:100%;
    }
```